# Get installation-date of Joomla and/or of a component?

Tags: php, model, jmodel

I would like to get the installation-date of my joomla-installation and/or of any component by writing a new method in a model of my component.

How could I solve this?

Answer (score 1):

On Linux the best you can do is work out the last modified time of a certain file by using filetime (http://php.net/filemtime).
So to work out the Joomla installation date you could run filetime on a file that is not likely to have been edited /components/index.html.

You could use the same principle for extensions by doing :

```
filetime('/components/com_foo/index.html')
```